# Third party js issue in DXP

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, liferay-dxp

I am trying to use [Progressbar js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js) in Liferay DXp custom plugin. It was working fine in 6.2 however it seems to be not working in DXP.

I have checked the standalone html with this plugin and it works fine however it is not working with DXP 7.0

I am getting

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: ProgressBar is not defined"

error.

> The file is well loaded on page but I still get this error

.

I have checked the version of Jquery and it's 2.1.4 in DXP 7.0. The plugin is well supported with this version of Jquery as it works fine on standalone html file.

Not sure if there is any issue with DXP while using third party js plugins as I have faced similar issue while using jquery cookie plugin.

Has anyone faced this issue or is there any way to use third party plugin in DXP?

The way I imported this pluigin in portlet is with annotation
"com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-javascript=/js/progressbar.min.js",

Since it was not working so I have added it in theme and tried but no luck.

Could anyone help me with this, please.

Answer (score 0):

> The way I imported this pluigin in portlet is with annotation `"com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-javascript=/js/progressbar.min.js"`

Check the generated markup, what actual URL is requested from the server, and if it's being served. I'm assuming that it's a 404 - for example because the file might be missing from your bundle, or in a different location.

If these hints don't help, please edit your question and create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)